# Spring EL no "principle" in authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-el

I've faced with discrepancy between Spring documentation and what I see as a result of my experiments. I have some method and I need to check permissions before method invocation and in accordance with spring docs I prepared the following:

```
@PreAuthorize("authentication.principle.company == #company.company")
public CompanyForm getCompanyForm(Company company) {
    //some code here
}
```

But surprisingly method invocation is denied due to this error:

`org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 15): Property or field 'principle' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken' - maybe not public?`

Could somebody point me to my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [Spring Security Javadocs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.html#getPrincipal--), the field in the authentication token is `principal`. You misspelled it.

```
@PreAuthorize("authentication.principal.company == #company.company")
public CompanyForm getCompanyForm(Company company) {
    //some code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the end of the day, you know :)